# Open Graph Meta Tags Not Being Read

Tags: facebook, web-applications, web, facebook-opengraph

Ok so I have scoured the internet for days and have yet to fix the problem I'm having with these open graph tags. I have a website, and on that website I have a facebook like button and a facebook comment box, both of them seem to work pretty well until the content is shared to Facebook. When someone likes or comments on the content, facebook shares it on the persons profile wall, but it does not use any of the OG meta tags. For example, if a visitor was to comment or like a post about what I posted, the shared link that would show up on their page would just be the URL and then a random image from the website page( not the one I selected).

Here is how my Open Graph tags are set up:

```html
  <head> 
      <meta property="og:type"   content="Cookies" /> 
      <meta property="og:url"    content="http://example.com" /> 
      <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Object" /> 
      <meta property="og:image"  content="https://Example.com/Images/Picture.png" /> 
  </head>
```

I have run the site through the Facebook linter, but all it brings me back is warnings:`Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

Everything I've been reading says I've set this up correctly, but for whatever reason It just isn't reading the page properly. The debugger page shows me 3 images it picks up, but they are the last 3 images at the bottom of the page. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: at the bottom of linter's result, there should be a link "See exactly what scraper see" or something like that. Check the raw data in final url and get the image url and test if its correct or not. If you can provide reference to you site I can take a look. I have had my share of facebook linter.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the link that is in the scraper is the proper one, just not the one it's using. The specific link I'm testing right now is `http://TheSnoopz.com/Sports/Post/Arod-Suspension` the link in the meta data tag should pull from `TheSnoopz.com/Images/Arod-Suspension.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the source at (http://TheSnoopz.com/Sports/Post/Arod-Suspension). The quickest way is removing `<!--Meta tags For Facebook--!>` or change it to a valid comment. i.e. `<!-- Meta tags For Facebook -->`. Wrong declaration is causing og meta tags not to render at all.

It seems your html has many errors. Please do validation check.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthesnoopz.com%2FSports%2FPost%2FArod-Suspension&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
I had exactly the same problem. Nearly a weak pounding my head over I don't know How many support/discussion forums.

[SOLUTION]

set your *og:title* url to exactly your convas https url which usually follows '?' in the end which I suppose is necessary... THAT'S IT!